# Shell Script for multithreading a process

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, unix

I am a Bioinformatician and recently stuck in a problem which requires some scripting to speed up my process. We have a software called PHASE and Command that i type in my command line to fire software is

```
./PHASE test.inp test.out
```

where PHASE is the name of the program and test.ip is the input file and test.out is the output file.It takes one core to run the above process which takes approx 3 hours to complete.

Now i have 1000 of input files say test1.inp,test2.inp,test3.inp.....and so on to test1000.inp and want to generate all 1000 output files..test1.out,test2.out.....test100.out using full capacity of my system which has 4 cores.

To use full capacity of my system I want to fire 4 instance of the above script that takes 4 input files like this...and generate 4 different outputs

```
./PHASE test1.inp test1.out
./PHASE test2.inp test2.out
./PHASE test3.inp test3.out
./PHASE test4.inp test4.out
```

After each job is finished and output file has been generated the script should again fire up the remaining input files until all are over..

```
./PHASE test5.inp test5.out
./PHASE test6.inp test6.out
./PHASE test7.inp test7.out
./PHASE test8.inp test8.out
```

and so on.....

How to write the script for the above process where the script takes advantage of 4 cores and speed up my process.

Comment: Multithreading, by nature, involves multiple threads **within a single process image**. As such, it requires that the process (`PHASE`, here) be written to support it. What you're asking about here is something somewhat different.

Comment: Note that if you have 4 processes, you almost certainly don't want to run exactly 4 processes.  You will probably want to run 8 or 12, since there will inevitably be some blocking on IO.  You may think your jobs are totally processor bound, but do some experimentation before blindly assuming that you want to run exactly the same number of jobs as you have cores.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU xargs, consider something like:

```
printf '%s\0' *.inp | xargs -0 -P 4 -n 1 \
  sh -c 'for f; do ./PHASE "$f" "${f%.inp}.out"' _
```

The `-P 4` is important here, indicating the number of processes to run in parallel.

If you have a very large number of inputs and they're fast to process, consider replacing `-n 1` with a larger number, to increase the number of inputs each shell instance iterates over -- decreasing shell startup costs, but also reducing granularity and, potentially, level of parallelism.

---

That said, if you *really* want to do batches of four (per your question), letting all four finish before starting the next four (which introduces some inefficiency, but *is* what you asked for), you could do something like this...

```
set -- *.inp                # set $@ to list of files matching *.imp
while (( $# )); do          # until we exhaust that list...
  for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do # loop over batches of four...
    # as long as there's a next argument, start a process for it, and take it off the list
    [[ $1 ]] && ./PHASE "$1" "${1%.imp}.out" & shift
  done
  wait                      # ...and wait for running processes to finish before proceeding
done
```

Comment: What is f ? Should i initialize f to 1000. What is the use of sh -c .?@charles Duffy

Comment: `f` iterates over filenames passed by `xargs` to the shell. No, you don't need to initialize it at all; the `for` loop assigns its values, which come from the glob expansion of `*.imp`.

Comment: `sh -c` invokes a shell; otherwise, you can't use shell directives in code invoked from xargs, since xargs uses an `execv`-family call to directly invoke the program named by its argument list (bypassing any shell).

Comment: xargs -P is almost certainly the solution you should adopt.  Don't bother trying shell hackery to make this work!

Comment: This solution will mix stdout/stderr from all the running jobs. This can become very messy. So if you are using stdout/stderr for debugging, then this is a bad solution.

Comment: Depends on how `./PHASE` structures its writes. If each individual line is an independent write call (shorter than the platform's page size), messiness isn't so likely. Indeed, for stderr, line buffering is the libc default.

Answer (score 2):

My money is on **GNU Parallel**, rather than *shell hackery*! Nice term @William-Pursell !

It looks like this:

```
parallel ./PHASE test{1}.inp test{1}.out ::: {1..1000}
```

It is:

- easy to write
- easy to read
- performant
- flexible

If you want to run 16 jobs at a time, just add `-j` like this:

```
parallel -j 16 ./PHASE ...
```

If you want to get a progress report, just add `-progress`, like this:

```
parallel --progress ./PHASE ...
```

If you want to add a bunch of extra servers all around your network to speed things up, just add their IP addresses with `-S`, like this:

```
parallel -S meatyServer1 -S meatyServer1 ./PHASE ...
```

If you want a log of when processes were started and when they completed, just do this:

```
parallel --joblog $HOME/parallelLog.txt
```

If you want to add check-pointing so your jobs can be stopped and restarted, which you almost certainly should with 3,000 hours of processing, that is also easy. There are many variants, but for example, you could skip jobs whose corresponding output files already exist, so that if you restart, you immediately carry on where you left off. I would make a little bash function and do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a function for "GNU Parallel" to call
checkpointedPHASE() {
    ip="test${1}.inp"
    op="test${1}.out"
    # Skip job if already done
    if [ -f "$op" ]; then
       echo Skipping $1 ...
    else
       ./PHASE "$ip" "$op"
    fi
}
export -f checkpointedPHASE

# Now start parallel jobs
parallel checkpointedPHASE {1} ::: {1..1000}
```

You are in good company doing Bioinformatics with **GNU Parallel** - [bioinformatics tutorial with GNU Parallel](https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/).

Comment: I would be more worried about `{1..1000}` expanding into an array too long to reliably fit on `ARG_MAX` more than anything else. For all that I distrust parallel due to its implementation complexity, it *is* a good tool for this job.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Given that ARG_MAX is typically 131,000 or so, and my 1,000 numbers are under 4 bytes each, I think they should fit ok. Also, the numbers can be generated many other ways and piped into Parallel's `stdin` if that is a concern. Or the input filenames could be sent to its `stdin` and it would adapt to however many files were present.

Comment: That's a very high value for "typical". Maybe if you're only talking modern 64-bit Linux, but I've seen values at/under 32k not so long ago at all. But, yes -- feeding filenames on stdin is how I'm doing it with xargs, so I agree that it's a working approach. :)

Comment: Aside: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the heads-up on my formatting - I will try and improve my ways :-)

Comment: If `PHASE` returns an error if it fails, then retrying/resuming could simply be done by `--resume-failed --joblog ...`.

Answer (score 1):

"multi-threading" is the wrong word for what you are trying to do.  You want to run multiple processes in parallel.  Multi-threading refers to having multiple threads of execution running in the same process.  Running all of the processes at once and letting the os schedule them for you has been mentioned, as has `xargs -P`, and you might want to look at gnu `parallel`.  You can also hack a solution in the shell, but this has several issues (namely, it is not even remotely robust).  The basic idea is to create a pipe and have each process write a token into the pipe when it is done.  At the same time, you read the pipe and start up a new process whenever a token appears.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash 

n=${1-4}  # Use first arg as number of processes to run, default is 4

trap 'rm -vf /tmp/fifo' 0
rm -f /tmp/fifo
mkfifo /tmp/fifo

cmd() {
    ./PHASE test$1.inp test$1.out
    echo $1 > /tmp/fifo
}

# spawn first $n processes
yes | nl | sed ${n}q | while read num line; do
        cmd $num &
done


# Spawn a new process whenever a running process terminates
yes | nl | sed -e 1,${n}d -e 1000q | {
while read num line; do
        read -u 5 stub # wait for one to terminate
        cmd $num &
done 5< /tmp/fifo
wait
} &
exec 3> /tmp/fifo
wait
```

Comment: I was *almost* ready to recommend GNU parallel myself, but then I remembered what its codebase looks like. Which... maybe I ought to get over my chauvinism regarding Perl (after all, I'm at least implicitly advocating doing nontrivial things in native bash by helping people with same), but it's still something of a gut reaction.

Comment: Never look at how the sausage is made!

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not support multi-threading, however it does support multi-processing. If you change your command to be:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
    ./PHASE test$i.inp test$i.out &
done
```

This will run each one a process and your computer will automatically schedule them based on how many core you have. 1000 Processes will have a lot of overhead compared to threads, but while not ideal it should still be fine.

Edit:
Here is a more advanced method if you want to prioritize getting progressive answers:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Number of cores and range end
n=4
e=1000

# This function will do the processing
process() {
    for ((i=$1; i <= $3; i += $2)); do
        ./PHASE test${i}.inp test${i}.out
        echo "Done $i"
    done
}

# For each core create a process and record the pid
for ((i=1; i <= n; i++)); do
    process $i $n $e &
done

# Wait for each process to complete
wait
```

Comment: `seq` is neither guaranteed to be present by POSIX not provided by bash. Consider using native C-style for loop syntax.

Comment: ...also, why index into `pids`? You could iterate over values rather than keys -- `for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do wait "$pid"; done` -- or accept the behavior of waiting for everything at once with `wait` having no arguments.

Comment: I'd also suggest avoiding the `function` keyword, which is POSIX-incompatible while having no benefit over the standardized syntax.

Comment: ...and there are a lot of missing quotes here; http://shellcheck.net/ will point them out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tips. I didn't even know about c style for loops.