# syntax for multithreading(?)/multiprocessing in a script

Tags: multithreading, bash, fork

I'm running some extremely lengthy simulations (on the order of days, and the only functionality build in to the simulator itself for multithreading/processing is to use PBS Server and have many separate nodes to which it can farm out).

I currently have a single VM running with 32 cores, ~120GB RAM on Ubuntu.

Each simulation currently runs on 1 core, but I have several files that I want to run concurrently to save time (e.g days rather than months!) - i.e. I would like to be running the simulation within my VM on each of the 32 or so cores.

So far I don't think my script correctly spawns multiple forked processes, as the output of top doesn't show a process for each.

Where am I going wrong exactly?

(Also on a related note, for a forked process (&) in a script, is it necessary to specify nohup (both on the simulation command itself, or for the script overall) - I suspect I'm being really daft here and should really be piping the STDOUT instead, and just nohupping the .sh file?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#####

pkgdir=~/Applications/itasser/
libdir=$pkgdir/itlib

for folder in `ls $1`;
    do
    datadir=`find ~/ -type d -name ${folder}`
    t_start=$(date +%s.%N)
    nohup perl ~/Applications/itasser/I-TASSERmod/runI-TASSER.pl -pkgdir $pkgdir -libdir $libdir -seqname $folder -datadir $datadir -java_home /usr/ &
    wait
    t_stop=$(date +%s.%N)
    dt=$(echo "$t_stop - $t_start" | bc)
    echo "itasser simulation for" $folder "took" $dt
done
```

Where `$1` is a folder I pass to the script (e.g. `~/testfiles/`).

I also suspect that my effort to time the perl script here will only work if it runs through each file sequentially, and won't correctly time each ideally forked process - but that's a separate issue.

Comment: `wait` waits for backgrounded jobs to finish before returning so `job &; wait` is the same as `job` (i.e. no backgrounding and no multiple jobs). Also don't [parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) just use a glob. Quote your variable expansions. And use `$()` instead of backticks (largely style but they are more consistent about quoting and the modern syntax).

Comment: So the solution would be actually to remove the &?  Thanks for the link about parsing ls, that syntax was actually some I borrowed from the devs of the Perl software I'm using - I'll replace it with something like `for folder in */ ;`

Comment: Your question confuses me. Are you running multiple VMs or not? What are you actually running on? I suspect the best solution would be to use `GNU Parallel` and it can schedule one, or more, tasks per core very simply.

Comment: Removing `&` would mean you can remove `wait` (as it would be a no-op at that point) but that would also remove all backgrounding. If you **want** tasks running in the background then you want `&` and *not* `wait`. Though that will run them *all* at the same time. As Mark said your situation and exact goal is not at all clear. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry yes on re-reading I realise it isn't the clearest - will edit to clarify.

How stupid, I didn't realise I had even put a `wait` in!

In short, yes I would like as many jobs running concurrently as possible, one for each input file.

By way of extension, should the ultimately work, if I want to analyse more jobs than there are cores available, will the underlying process scheduler handle that and 'pause' the loop until a core frees up - or do I need to hardcode this behaviour somehow?

Comment: When you spawn a process, the OS will try to do that immediately.  Spawning many more than the CPU can handle will lead to thrashing.  So you want to control the number of jobs you are running.  Again, this sounds like you are reinventing `parallel` -- there's a fair number of questions similar to yours where this is answered in detail.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34910148/2836621 It is very similar to what you are doing, I think.

Comment: Oh interesting, i saw that thread but actually stopped just short of your answer! Am I right in thinking then, that instead of invoking the `perl` command for each file, I would then use something to the effect of `parallel -j 16 perl script.pl inputfile{1,2,...16}`?

Comment: I think you would need to put 3 colons before your input files... `parallel -j 16 perl script.pl ::: inputfile{1,2,...16}`

Comment: I do at least have multiple simulations running with my bodge-job, but as you say it doesn't address any CPU thrashing. From talking to other people, the suggestions were `parallel` as you advised, or utilising some fork module/functionality in perl.